# How to validate UITextfield that satisfies 5 different conditions using shouldChangeCharactersInrange method?

Tags: ios, swift, regex, uitextfield

I’m trying to validate a Password Textfield in realtime (Swift 4.2 & Xcode 10.2.1).

My question is how to validate the conditions listed below in UITextField's ***shouldChangeCharactersInrange*** method?

- Minimum 8 characters
- Maximum 50 characters
- Minimum 1 alphabet
- Minimum 1 number
- No special characters

Also, there will be a gray color tick image on the left side of all 4 validation messages. As long as the condition are not met, image will be gray color tick. If validation succeeds, tick images will turn to green.

When I tap the Confirm button in the screen, I will have to call Set New Password API. I'm thinking about setting a bool **isValidationSuccess** to true when all the above conditions are met in shouldChangeCharactersInrange method.

On Confirm button tap, api will only be called if isValidationSuccess is true.

This is what I have managed so far. Could you please help me?

```
// MARK: - TextField delegate methods
extension SetNewPasswordViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
        let minPasswordLength = 8
        let currentString: NSString = newPasswordTextfield.text! as NSString
        let newString: NSString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

        if newString.length < minPasswordLength {
            minimumCharacterValidationImage.isHighlighted = false
        } else {
            minimumCharacterValidationImage.isHighlighted = true
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `.replacingCharacters` if your method returns a Boolean? I think you may use `range`, something like: `return newPasswordTextfield.text.range(of: "^(?=\\D*\\d)(?=\\d*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,50}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Could please validate the solution I found? I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a regex based on the answers provided and it works. Could you guys please validate this.

- Minimum 8 characters
- Maximum 50 characters
- Minimum 1 alphabet
- Minimum 1 number
- No special characters

**Common Class**

```
class Common: NSObject {

        // MARK: - Password TextField Validations
        static func isValidPassword(_ input: String) -> Bool {
            print("validate Password: \(input)")
            let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,50}$"
            return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: input)
        }
    }
```

**ViewController Code**

```
// MARK: - TextField delegate methods
extension SetNewPasswordViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
        if textField == newPasswordTextfield {

            if let text = newPasswordTextfield.text,
                let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
                let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange,
                                                           with: string)
                if Common.isValidPassword(updatedText) == true {
                    minimumCharacterValidationImage.isHighlighted = true
                    minimumAlphabetValidationImage.isHighlighted = true
                    minimumNumberValidationImage.isHighlighted = true
                    noSpecialCharacterValidationImage.isHighlighted = true
                    minimumCharacterValidationImage.isHighlighted = true
                    confirmButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0.5, blue:0.54, alpha:1)
                    isValidPasswordStatus = true
                } else {
                    minimumCharacterValidationImage.isHighlighted = false
                    minimumAlphabetValidationImage.isHighlighted = false
                    minimumNumberValidationImage.isHighlighted = false
                    noSpecialCharacterValidationImage.isHighlighted = false
                    confirmButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.4, green:0.47, blue:0.5, alpha:1)
                    isValidPasswordStatus = false
                }
            }

        }
        return true
    }

}
```

EDIT : As there was no other answers and the one above works for the specified conditions, I'm marking my own answer as the accepted one. Just to be clear, I found the solution using the comments of Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: API call in button action will only be called if isValidPasswordStatus is true.

Comment: If you use `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES` you do not need anchors in the regex at start/end. Also, use the principle of contrast. Also, `\d` matches more than `[0-9]`. Use `let passwordRegex = "(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,50}"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the regex. I have one more question.
How can I change the isHighlightedvalue of ImageViews whenever a particular validation succeeds?
Currently, the entire regex has to be passed for "if Common.isValidPassword(updatedText)" condition to be true.
What I meant was, if a single number is entered "minimumNumberValidationImage" should become highlighted.

Comment: Then do each validation step one by one, do not use a regex crammed with lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for this.

```
func isValidPassword() -> Bool {
    let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,50}$"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: self)
}

extension SetNewPasswordViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
        if textField == passwordTextField {
            if passwordTextField.isValidPassword == true
            {
                return true
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified you answer and found a solution. 
I don't understand how this condition works. (if passwordTextField.isValidPassword == true)
We have to pass the password textfield text to the regex function and validate that string.