# Swift UITextfield and CharacterSet cannot delete previous user's input

Tags: swift

I'm writing code restricting the user's ability to enter alphabetic texts and repeating decimal into the textField.
In the code below my text field were able to accept only user's numeric input and so does the code I commented out however, the only difference is the user can't delete after he/she type in a number.
Whereas, the user were able to delete after he/she type in the number if I replace the current code with the commented code.

[image]

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let existingTextHasDecimalSeperator = textField.text?.range(of: ".")
        let replacementTextHasDecimalSeperator = string.range(of: ".")
        
//        let replacementTextCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
//        let replacementTextIsAlphabetic = (replacementTextCharacterSet.isDisjoint(with: CharacterSet.letters) == false) 
          ///This means an element in set A intersect with an element in set B
        
   let replacementTextCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
   let replacementTextIsAlphabetic = (replacementTextCharacterSet.isSubset(of: CharacterSet.letters) == true)
   if (existingTextHasDecimalSeperator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeperator != nil) || replacementTextIsAlphabetic {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
```

The code that was commented out above work as intended however, the current code isn't and I failed to understand why.

Can you please explain to me the reason why I can't delete what I input afterward.
If I use `.isSubset = true` the logic seems the same to me.

Comment: I have tried restricting user input in the past like this and it results in highly unmaintainable code. instead, If it is possible for you to let the user type whatever he wants or at least restrict to specific characters, you can use regex/ NSPredicate to validate the resultant text. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456555/how-to-validate-uitextfield-that-satisfies-5-different-conditions-using-shouldch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to handle backspace in your `shouldChangeCharactersIn` function
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield

> string
>
> The replacement string for the specified range. During typing,
> this parameter normally contains only the single new character that
> was typed, but it may contain more characters if the user is pasting
> text. **When the user deletes one or more characters, the replacement
> string is empty.**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if (string.isEmpty){
            print("Backspace")
        }
        return true
    }
```